# How to get memory available or used in C#

Tags: c#, memory-management

How can I get the available RAM or memory used by the application?

Comment: You should take a look at the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

Comment: Note, physical RAM currently used is the working set, memory allocated falls into private or shared bytes (depending on the type of allocation).

Answer (score 217):

You can use:

```
Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
```

To get the current process and use:

```
proc.PrivateMemorySize64;
```

To get the private memory usage. For more information look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.privatememorysize64).

Comment: It should probably be noted that a call to GetCurrentProcess will itself allocate quite a lot of resources. Call Dispose on the returned process when done, or wrap the whole code in a "using" scope.

Comment: Namespace:  System.Diagnostics
Assembly:  System (in System.dll)

Comment: I'd like to also add that the PrivateMemorySize64 property (+ other properties) itself is not automatically updated until Refresh() is called. (It's mentioned on the page at the link above.)

Comment: See this other similar question for more answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032515/how-to-get-the-amount-of-memory-used-by-an-application

Comment: @ScottRhee correct me if i'm wrong - but I'd add that the property values are "up to date" at the moment that you call `GetCurrentProcess`, but only need to be refreshed if you are doing other operations prior to accessing the properties. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.refresh?view=netframework-4.8) - **Remarks** say the properties are correct at moment the process snapshot is created.

Comment: If my C# application is running in 32bit (for reasons I don't want to get into), do I still check PrivateMemorySize64 or should I be checking PrivateMemorySize?

Comment: @scott.korin you should still use PrivateMemorySize64, the 64 refers to it's type which is a long, PrivateMemorySize only return an int.

Answer (score 46):

You might want to check the [GC.GetTotalMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx) method.

It retrieves the number of bytes currently thought to be allocated by the garbage collector.

Comment: Only in managed heaps though.  Arkain's answer should give both native and managed heaps.

Answer (score 36):

[System.Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) has [WorkingSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.workingset.aspx)-
a 64-bit signed integer containing the number of bytes of physical memory mapped to the process context.

In .NET Core 3.0 and later (aka .NET 5 and later), you can use [`GC.GetGCMemoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.gc.getgcmemoryinfo) to get information about memory used by the GC heap and how much memory the GC thinks is available. .NET internally [uses this data](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a891aed8e03a225d8b31bbea0ae1a86972adc819/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/Utilities.cs#L38) to calculate memory pressure. The memory pressure [is used](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a891aed8e03a225d8b31bbea0ae1a86972adc819/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/TlsOverPerCoreLockedStacksArrayPool.cs#L190) to decide when to trim the System.Buffers.ArrayPool.

Comment: Can you (or someone at all) give an example of how to use PerformanceCounter to get the system available/used memory?

Comment: I removed the reference to PerformanceCounter, as it was not helpful. I added some information about GC.GetGCMemoryInfo, which is probably more useful.

Comment: Note you need to call Process.Refresh() to get updated values.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to [@JesperFyhrKnudsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750595/1766014)'s answer and [@MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/553609/mathias-lykkegaard-lorenzen)'s comment, you'd better `dispose` the returned `Process` after using it.

So, In order to dispose the `Process`, you could wrap it in a `using` scope or calling `Dispose` on the returned process (`proc` variable).

1. `using` scope:

   ```
   var memory = 0.0;
   using (Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
   {
       // The proc.PrivateMemorySize64 will returns the private memory usage in byte.
       // Would like to Convert it to Megabyte? divide it by 2^20
          memory = proc.PrivateMemorySize64 / (1024*1024);
   }
   ```
2. Or `Dispose` method:

   ```
   var memory = 0.0;
   Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
   memory = Math.Round(proc.PrivateMemorySize64 / (1024*1024), 2);
   proc.Dispose();
   ```

Now you could use the `memory` variable which is converted to Megabyte.

Comment: NB: One megabyte is 2^20 not 1e+6

Comment: One note. In C# `^` is bitwise XOR, not power. So just use `proc.PrivateMemorySize64 / (1024*1024)`, or `proc.PrivateMemorySize64 / (1 << 20)`

Comment: You missed parenthesis, should be `proc.PrivateMemorySize64 / (1024 * 1024)` as multiplication does not have a priority over division.

Comment: @LaurynasLazauskas I've updated the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Look [here](http://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2009/10/22/how-to-get-cpu-and-memory-usage-c-net/) for details.

```
private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
private PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitialiseCPUCounter();
    InitializeRAMCounter();
    updateTimer.Start();
}

private void updateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = "CPU Usage: " +
    Convert.ToInt32(cpuCounter.NextValue()).ToString() +
    "%";

    this.textBox2.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ramCounter.NextValue()).ToString()+"Mb";
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

private void InitialiseCPUCounter()
{
    cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
    "Processor",
    "% Processor Time",
    "_Total",
    true
    );
}

private void InitializeRAMCounter()
{
    ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes", true);

}
```

If you get value as 0 it need to call `NextValue()` twice. Then it gives the actual value of CPU usage. See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/how-to-read-performance-counters-ryan-byington).

Answer (score 0):

For the complete system you can add the Microsoft.VisualBasic Framework as a reference;

```
 Console.WriteLine("You have {0} bytes of RAM",
        new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory);
        Console.ReadLine();
```