# starting memory of process

Tags: c#, memory

How to get the start memory location of a process in c#

I have been doing this, but do not know

```
Process currentProcess  = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
long totalBytesOfMemoryUsed = currentProcess.WorkingSet64;

currentProcess.ProcessName
currentProcess.PrivateMemorySize
currentProcess.VirtualMemorySize
```

Comment: Why do you need this information?  (It is not 100% clear what information you need.)

Comment: Your question isn't exactly a duplicate, but it's quite close to http://stackoverflow.com/q/842585/960195.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
currentProcess.Modules[0].BaseAddress
```

Comment: @cMinor: Well, they're process modules. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.modules.aspx See the Remarks section. Index `0` is always the base process.