# Source of the inbuilt method getAvailableRam

Tags: c#

I need the code or the definition of the method `getAvailableRam` used in C# to find the memory usage of the computer.

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750574/how-to-get-memory-available-or-used-in-c](this post) for more info

Comment: There are no functions in C#, there are methods, every method belongs to a class, and every class belongs to a DLL or an application. Where did you take this method name from? Where does it belong? Who wrote it?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Mb", ramCounter.NextValue());
    }
}
```