# Equivalent of Runtime class (of java) in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is their is an Equivalent of Runtime class (of java) in c#
Actually I am trying to convert these operation to c#

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        return runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to get at the current memory usage, you want the [`GC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0fwz4wc.aspx) class.

For example:

```
long memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true); // Allow a brief time for GC/finalization
```

The `GC` class is also where you can find members to suggest garbage collection, wait for pending finalizers, and the like.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the answer,
But I wonder whats the equivalent of runtime.freeMemory(); in C#

Comment: EDIT: nevermind, misunderstood.  This help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750574/how-to-get-memory-available-or-used-in-c-sharp

Comment: @AnuragSharma: You don't need to do that in .NET, as `GetTotalMemory` only returns memory known to be allocated to objects - it doesn't include the "allocated but currently unused" memory.