# How to get memory available or used in C# .net core / .net standard

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

Is there a way to know the current used memory in the current process?

I checked many questions:
[How to get the amount of memory used by an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032515/how-to-get-the-amount-of-memory-used-by-an-application)

[How to get memory available or used in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750574/how-to-get-memory-available-or-used-in-c-sharp)

They are not available in .Net Standard 1.6.

Comment: https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Diagnostics.Process.PrivateMemorySize64

Comment: Not available in .NET Standard 1.6

Comment: So sorry @R.Richards the one you mentioned is available, but PrivateMemorySize is not.

Comment: https://gunnarpeipman.com/dotnet-core-system-memory/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you can check how it is done in [HealthChecks project](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/HealthChecks/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.HealthChecks/Checks/SystemChecks.cs). You can use `Process` class from `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

*** EDIT ***

[System.Diagnostics.Process Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.Process/) might need to be added.

Only xxxx64 memory properties are supported in .NET Standard (for example PrivateMemorySize64 and not PrivateMemorySize).

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks, it turned out that only the XXXXX64 (for example PrivateMemorySize64) properties are supported in .NET Standard (for example proc.PrivateMemorySize64)

Comment: .NET Core 2.1, added System.Diagnostics.Process NuGet package, but all "64" properties return 0 under Ubuntu (WSL).

Comment: I encountered the same problem for ubuntu (I am running in docker skd-runtime 2.2 ).