# How to get current CPU and RAM usage, and also how much is available in C# .NET core without looping over all processes?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cpu-usage, ram

Is there any method in C# to have the current amount of memory used and how much is available, without needing to loop over all processes and add each workingset64 value?

Comment: do you mean resource usage of current process, or other processes?

Comment: of all the processes running at the moment, say they are using 14GB of RAM, so how do i get this value in my code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the size of available system memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296211/how-to-get-the-size-of-available-system-memory)

Comment: No, it doesn't :( I need something specific to .netcore as my app is cross-platform

Comment: how about [How to get memory available or used in C# .net core / .net standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45268831/1518100)

Comment: You cannot get that information in pure .NET Core yet. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22948 - If you just want to find out how much memory all processes are using, you can enumerate all Process objects and tally up information. It won't tell you how much memory is available in the computer, however.

Comment: @LeiYang Yeah that is what can be done currently but as Lasse V. Karlsen mentioned we need to do it for all processes, hence a loop. Thanks for sharing both of you.

Comment: Seems someone has created a project for this that maybe can tend to your needs. https://github.com/Jinjinov/Hardware.Info

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could do this to solve your issue: https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-memory-health-check/

Comment: you should reference your work. https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-memory-health-check/

Comment: My bad, I found it on an old repo instead.