# Is there a command line utility/wrapper around resmon.exe?

Tags: c#, performance, wmi, perfmon, resource-monitor

I wish to use resmon.exe to monitor usage of my application exe. 
Is there an equivalent WMI or command line switch that i can use to query data form resmon.exe
I wish to monitor Memory usage of my application(as in Private memory, Shareable, and Overall ) when my application is launched, then after 30 secs, and so.

Comment: What specifically do you want to do? resmon displays metrics likely gathered from querying Performance Counters, which you can do directly yourself.

Comment: I wish to monitor Memory usage of my application(as in Private memory, Shareable, and Overall ) when my application is launched, then after 30 secs, and so.

Comment: There are built in ways to do this, many duplicate questions here if you search, E.g. [How to get memory available or used in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750574/how-to-get-memory-available-or-used-in-c-sharp) - If this does not include the data you want you would use a `PerformanceCounter`