# Get information about RAM during the run of a program

Tags: c#

I've got two methods. I want to test its performance.

The time of its work I can get with stopwatch. But how to get information about RAM?Are there any classes for it?

Or I will have to get it from task manager manually?(stop program+run tm+continue program)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Poll C# app's memory usage at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463595/poll-c-sharp-apps-memory-usage-at-runtime)

Comment: Have a look at the dupe I posted in the previous comment. Or also you can use a memory profiler that gives you even much more infos.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64
```

Comment: What's the difference between that, Process.PagedMemorySize64 and Process.PrivateMemorySize64 (the accepted answer and alternate suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463595/poll-c-sharp-apps-memory-usage-at-runtime)?

Comment: @EricJ: I'm embarrassed to admit that I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Jon Skeet's blog on similar subject - http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings.aspx.

Basically use [GC.GetTotalMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx)

```
  long before = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    // do something 
  long after = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

  Console.WriteLine("Diff:{0}" after - before;);
```

Note that TaskManager shows how much memory process is allocated, you want to see how much memory CLR is allocated for alive objects at particular point.