# get memory space in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory

How would you do this in c#, an example in c++ is:

```
void PrintMemoryInfo( DWORD processID )
{
     std::ofstream fs("d:\\processInfo.txt"); 
     fs<<"Information of Process:\n";

    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
    fs<<"\nProcess ID: %u\n"<<processID;

    hProcess = OpenProcess(  PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                    PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                    FALSE, processID );
  if (NULL == hProcess) return;

    if ( GetProcessMemoryInfo( hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)) )    {



        fs<< "\tPageFaultCount: 0x%08X\n" << pmc.PageFaultCount;
        fs<< "\tYour app's PEAK MEMORY CONSUMPTION: 0x%08X\n"<<pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize;
        fs<< "\tYour app's CURRENT MEMORY CONSUMPTION: 0x%08X\n"<< pmc.WorkingSetSize;
        fs<< "\tQuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n"<< 
                  pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
        fs<< "\tQuotaPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n"<< 
                  pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
        fs<< "\tQuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n"<< 
                  pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
        fs<< "\tQuotaNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n"<< 
                  pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
        fs<< "\tPagefileUsage: 0x%08X\n"<< pmc.PagefileUsage; 
        fs<< "\tPeakPagefileUsage: 0x%08X\n"<< 
                  pmc.PeakPagefileUsage;                  
    }
    fs.close();
    CloseHandle( hProcess);
}

int main( )
{
  PrintMemoryInfo( GetCurrentProcessId() );

    return 0;
}
```

but in c#?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few other articles that describe getting a running application's memory footprint:

[Poll C# app's memory usage at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463595/poll-c-sharp-apps-memory-usage-at-runtime)

[Memory usage in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755919/memory-usage-in-c-sharp)

TL;DR;

```
// get the current process
Process currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();

// get the physical mem usage
long totalBytesOfMemoryUsed = currentProcess.WorkingSet64;
```

Comment: I get Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Process' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to add 'using System.Diagnostics;' (without quotes) to the top of your source file to reference System.Diagnostics (which contains the Process class you are trying to reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using System.Diagnostics.Process class.
Please, have a look at: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx