# How to retrieve committed memory via C++

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, memory-leaks

I've found several answers to this question here on SO, but none that answers my question.
I'm trying to track down some memory leaks in our unmanaged C++ application, and from reading the following, it seems that "Memory - Commit Size" is the best metric to use when monitoring memory usage:
http://forum.sysinternals.com/virtual-private-bytes-and-working-set_topic18296.html

Here's the explanation of the various metrics reported by Windows Task Manager:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-do-the-task-manager-memory-columns-mean

I've found the following that describes how to retrieve the Working Set data for a named process:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76yt3c0w.aspx

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes =
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(theprocessName);
System.Diagnostics.Process process = processes[0];
```

However, this mentions nothing about Committed Memory:

Can anyone help?
Paul

Comment: Note that I updated the tags to include C++ and winapi as these are key to categorizing your question, more so than "memory" and "leak".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to use [`GetProcessMemoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219.aspx). This populates a [`PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684877.aspx) structure.

The key element of this structure you'll be interested in is

> **PagefileUsage** The Commit Charge value in bytes for this process. Commit Charge is the total amount of memory that the memory manager has committed for a running process.

- [Collecting Memory Usage Information For a Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682050.aspx)

Comment: @Jonathan. Is it possible to access this function using C#? It seems I'm not the only person who would like to know this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799147/get-memory-space-in-c-sharp
Thanks again.

Comment: @pau The Win32 API is made available to .NET through [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32).